# User input of integer followed by garbage

Tags: c++, error-handling, user-input, cin

In my simple `Fraction` class, I have the following method to get user input for the `numerator`, which works fine for checking garbage input like `garbage`, but will not recognize user input which starts with an integer, and is followed by garbage, `1 garbage` or `1garbage`.

```
void Fraction::inputNumerator()
{
    int inputNumerator;

    // loop forever until the code hits a BREAK
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Enter the numerator: ";

        // attempt to get the int value from standard input
        std::cin >> inputNumerator;

        // check to see if the input stream read the input as a number
        if (std::cin.good()) {

            numerator = inputNumerator;
            break;

        } else {

            // the input couldn't successfully be turned into a number, so the
            // characters that were in the buffer that couldn't convert are
            // still sitting there unprocessed.  We can read them as a string
            // and look for the "quit"

            // clear the error status of the standard input so we can read
            std::cin.clear();

            std::string str;
            std::cin >> str;

            // Break out of the loop if we see the string 'quit'
            if (str == "quit") {
                std::cout << "Goodbye!" << std::endl;
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }

            // some other non-number string.  give error followed by newline
            std::cout << "Invalid input (type 'quit' to exit)" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I saw a few posts on using the `getline` method for this, but they didn't compile when I tried them, and I'm having trouble finding the original post, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better check as follows:

```
// attempt to get the int value from standard input
if(std::cin >> inputNumerator)
{
    numerator = inputNumerator;
    break;
} else { // ...
```

Or yes: Follow recommendations to parse a complete input line combining `std::getline()` and `std::istringstream` appropriately.

Comment: @doctordoder Bwoooah! That quick at my 1st shot, really??

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't let me accept until like 10 minutes have passed lol i feel bad every time that happens.

Comment: @doctordoder Upvoted your question in revenge :D! Seriosly: It's not a really well suited question for SO, and that my 1st shot answer caught up all the problems indicates that. But for now let us all be happy as we are ;) ...